# iOS 13 stability issues (UI + Background operations)

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

We've had an app in the app store for roughly a year and are currently on release 4.x. Having upgraded to iOS 13.x a few hundred users are reporting strange issues surrounding logging in to the application and performing simple tasks. These range from app crashing to obtaining subscription receipts to app hanging. The users affected all have varying devices and are running iOS 13.x. These issues didn't appear in iOS 12 so were stumped.

We'd normally triage these issues and release a fix but the problem is that we can't find anything wrong and the other users (remaining 90%) are unaffected by these issues. This leads us to the conclusion that something is inherently wrong with the latest release of iOS.

Has anyone else encountered issues regarding iOS 13 and user access, or noticed an increase in crash rates as a result of iOS 13?

Thanks

Comment: Download your app in iOS 13 device, run it throughly. You will definitely find the issue.

Comment: We have done - in various states and scenarios.

Comment: Add your results for iOS 13 in your post.

Comment: There are no results as everything works in our tests and from the app store direct. We've worked closely with our users affected by this and their device settings match ours yet they experience issues. Their accounts are also fine as we can log in from our devices perfectly.

Comment: It would either be their device or iOS 13.

Comment: There are lots of changes in iOS13, which are expected to be handled by the developer. Are you sure you personally checked each and every condition in which user faced issue?

Comment: We have checked every condition - The part that's confusing is why only a percentage of our user base are affected. Unless a specific release of versioned iPhones have issues with iOS 13 but we would have seen something in the support forums.

Comment: Test on physical devices your seeing issues on. The simulator is great but not perfect. Test both cell/wifi. iOS came with a lot of little changes in functionality.

Comment: We always test on devices, no one should test on Simulators anymore as they're not a decent representation of device.